# Double Acquire a Spinlock in XV6

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, xv6

As we know, xv6 doesn't let a spinlock be acquired twice (even by a process itself).

I am trying to add this feature which lets a process to acquire a lock more than once.
In order to reach this, I am adding an attribute called `lock_holder_pid` to the `struct spinlock` which is supposed to hold the pid of the process which has acquired this lock.

The only file I have changed is `spinlock.c`

Here is my new `acquire()` function:

```
// Acquire the lock.
// Loops (spins) until the lock is acquired.
// Holding a lock for a long time may cause
// other CPUs to waste time spinning to acquire it.
void
acquire(struct spinlock *lk)
{
  pushcli(); // disable interrupts to avoid deadlock.

  
  uint cur_proc_pid = myproc()->pid; //Added by me
  
  
  if (holding(lk) && lk->lock_holder_pid == cur_proc_pid) //Added by me
  {
      popcli();
      return;
  }

  if(holding(lk) && lk->lock_holder_pid != cur_proc_pid) //Added by me
    panic("acquire");
  

  /* Commented by me
  if(holding(lk)) 
    panic("acquire");
  */


  // The xchg is atomic.
  while(xchg(&lk->locked, 1) != 0)
    ;

  
  lk-> lock_holder_pid = cur_proc_pid; //Added by me
  

  // Tell the C compiler and the processor to not move loads or stores
  // past this point, to ensure that the critical section's memory
  // references happen after the lock is acquired.
  __sync_synchronize();

  // Record info about lock acquisition for debugging.
  lk->cpu = mycpu();
  getcallerpcs(&lk, lk->pcs);
}
```

I also changed the `initlock()` function to this:

```
void
initlock(struct spinlock *lk, char *name)
{
  lk->name = name;
  lk->locked = 0;
  lk->cpu = 0;
  lk->lock_holder_pid = -1; //Added by me
}
```

The last function I modified is:

```
void
release(struct spinlock *lk)
{
  if(!holding(lk))
    panic("release");

  lk->pcs[0] = 0;
  lk->cpu = 0;
  lk->lock_holder_pid = -1; //Added by me



...
```

The problem is that the xv6 terminal get's stuck when booting with the message:

```
Booting from Hard Disk...
```

As far as I have understood, the line causing the problem is:

```
uint cur_proc_pid = myproc()->pid;
```

When I comment this line and only set lock_holder_pid to a constant number, it boots successfully.

Can anyone please help me with this?

The sections in the code marked with "Added by me" are the parts I have added.

Comment: Note the race between testing holder and setting holder.

Comment: @stark Could you please provide a more detailed explanation? Well, I can't acquire another lock in this acquire function. Should I implement some kind of semaphore to avoid this race condition?

Comment: Perhaps it would make more sense to allow a CPU to acquire the lock recursively rather than allowing a process to acquire the lock recursively. Also, it would need to be reference counted, requiring as many unlocks as locks.

Comment: @IanAbbott How can I allow the CPU to do such so? Should I change other files of the kernel? I would be thankful if you could please provide a more detailed explanation about reference counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because you are trying to have access to a field of a null struct (`myproc()->pid`).

As you may know, `myproc()` returns a process running on the current processor. If you look at `main.c`, you may notice that the bootstrap processor starts running there. Therefore, if we can find a function which calls the `acquire()` function before setting up the first process, the problem will be solved.

If you take a close look at the `kinit1` function, you can realize that the `acquire` function is called in it. Consequently, we found a function that uses the `acquire` function, even before initializing the `ptable` struct. Therefore, when you try to access the `myproc()` value, it is not initialized yet.